# Orchestration of Apache Spark using Apache Oozie

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-spark, oozie

We are thinking of the integration of apache spark in our calculation process where we at first wanted to use apache oozie and standard MR or MO (Map-Only) jobs.

After some research several **questions** remain:

1. Is it possible to orchestrate an apache spark process by using apache oozie? If yes, how?
2. Is oozie necessary anymore or could spark handle orchestration by itself? (*unification seems to be one of the main concerns in spark*)

Please **consider** the following **scenarios** when answering:

1. executing a work flow every 4 hours
2. executing a work flow whenever specific data is accessible
3. trigger a work flow and configure it with parameters

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Don't know much about Oozie, but I would say for spark go as simple as possible, since most of the flow handling is done within the job

Comment: While doing this we have run into the Spark Classpath problem several times. We have unresolved issues trying to get Spark to see jars on HDFS.  Instead it returns with "Skip remote jar" error as in this post: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3C1402447738231-7356.post@n3.nabble.com%3E  I will post again if we find a solution

Comment: Haven't tried it though
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1983

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it is still not included for proper testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark is supported in Oozie 4.2 as an action type, see [docs](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html). The scenarios you mentioned are common Oozie features.